# How is this the jet of $e^{sin t}$?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Please could someone help me understand the following statement:

We can work out $k$-jets of composites by 'neglecting higher terms'. For example, the $4$-jet of $e^{\sin t}$ at $0$ is obtained from

$$ 1 + (t - {1\over 6}t^3) + {1\over 2}(t - {1\over 6}t^3)^2 + {1\over 6}(t - {1\over 6}t^3)^3 + {1\over 24}(t - {1\over 6}t^3)^4$$

I see that this is the first few terms of the power series of $e^x$ evaluated at $t - {1\over 6}t^3$.

> Why does evaluating the series of $e^x$ at $t - {1\over 6}t^3$ yield
>   the series of $e^{\sin t}$?

Answer (score 2):

Well you only want the $4$-jet, so you can throw away any terms in the Taylor series of $\sin t$ of degree higher than $4$ since this these won't contribute to the $4$-jet of $e^{\sin t}\,,$ so you just use $t-\frac{t^3}{6}\,.$ However it's not true as you wrote that evaluating the series of $e^x$ at $t−\frac{t^3}{6}$ yields the series of $e^{\sin t}\,,$ if by series you mean Taylor series.

Comment: Thank you, you caught me: I did mean Taylor series when I wrote series. But the thing above is really the (truncated) Taylor series of $e^x$ evaluated at the truncated Taylor series of $\sin x$, no? (where by truncated I mean on both sides: constant term as well as higher order terms)

Comment: @MichaeldeSanta Yes it is.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$
\sin t = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k} \frac{t^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}
  = t - \frac{t^{3}}{3!} + \frac{t^{5}}{5!} - \cdots,
$$
you have $\sin t = t - \frac{t^{3}}{6}$ up to order four.

Comment: Great, thank you. I love it when I get an answer that makes it so obvious that I mentally *facepalm* myself.